# docker-compose not found under WSL 2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've got Windows system with Alpine WSL2 integration, and cannot run docker-compose under it. Here is log of my actions in WSL2:

```
ZHOPOZAVR:~# docker -v
Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414fdcb23a66e8fabbef0a560ef1769eace5
ZHOPOZAVR:~# docker-compose -v
/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-compose: line 13: /usr/bin/docker-compose: not found
ZHOPOZAVR:~# ls -al /usr/bin | grep docker-compose
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            56 Jan 13 05:41 docker-compose -> /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker-compose
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            59 Jan 13 05:41 docker-compose-v1 -> /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker-compose-v1
ZHOPOZAVR:~# /usr/bin/docker-compose -v
-ash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: not found
```

WSL2 integration is enabled in my Docker Desktop:

[image]

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with image of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your image of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: Have you made sure that wsl2 is enabled for your distro? `wsl -l -v`

Comment: And also according to https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/  "The Docker-WSL integration components running in your distro depend on glibc. This can cause issues when running musl-based distros such as Alpine Linux. Alpine users can use the alpine-pkg-glibc package to deploy glibc alongside musl to run the integration." So this may be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that somehow Apline WSL doesn't work with docker-compose. Ubuntu works just fine.